# XmlTextReader jumping every next node

Tags: vb.net

Probably simple question but i cant resolve it myself. I got xml which contain a lot of nodes, what i want to get is only those nodes where node element is "equipment.FanTray". The problem is its taking first then it goes to 3rd then it goes to 5th and so on..

```
equipment.FanTray      <----found
equipment.FanTray     
equipment.FanTray      <----found
equipment.FanTray
equipment.FanTray      <----found
equipment.FanTray
equipment.FanTray      <----found
equipment.FanTray
equipment.FanTray      <----found
```

my code is simple:

```
  Dim reader As Xml.XmlTextReader = New Xml.XmlTextReader("C:\Users\user\Desktop\ifile.xml") 

 Dim myList As New List(Of String)
        While (reader.Read())

 Select Case reader.NodeType
                Case XmlNodeType.Element  

                            If reader.Name = "equipment.FanTray" And reader.IsStartElement Then

                                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadOuterXml())


                            End If

      End Select
        End While
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks good to me. How about you use only 1 `Select Case`? 
That's the whole Point of a `Select Case`;)

```
Dim reader As Xml.XmlTextReader = New Xml.XmlTextReader("C:\Users\user\Desktop\ifile.xml") 
Dim myList As New List(Of String)

While (reader.Read())

    Select Case reader.NodeType

        Case XmlNodeType.Element 'Display beginning of element.

            If reader.Name = "equipment.FanTray" And reader.IsStartElement Then

                Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadOuterXml())

            End If

    End Select

End While
```

Comment: i am using only one - i pasted not correctly - now i corrected but the same behaviour it takes always skipping next one and jumping to + 1 further